# How can I include Guzzle as a library in a distribution?

Tags: 7, theming, distributions

I'm working on [Open Atrium 2](https://drupal.org/project/openatrium) and we'd like to include [Guzzle](https://drupal.org/project/guzzle) with the initial install so that we can build some integration features on top of it.

Usually, including a library just means adding the library to the drush make file, but Guzzle is more complicated because:

1. it has a few dependencies.
2. it's meant to be installed by Composer or Pear, not by direct download.
3. it's not on [the packaging whitelist on Drupal.org](https://drupal.org/packaging-whitelist), but I can request that it be added since the license doesn't conflict.

So how can I make this happen? Is there a pre-bundled-and-ready-to-use package somewhere that includes all dependencies, in which case I can just request that that be whitelisted for Drupal.org and use that? Or is installing Guzzle tricker than just including a bunch of files that can be placed in `sites/all/libraries`?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I disabled composer system wide on my machine and create a make file and it works fine installing Drupal 7 core plus the following modules: composer, composer_autoload & guzzle.

This is the content of [platform.make](https://gist.github.com/jmolivas/6946709)

```
$Id$

; API

api = 2

; Core

core = 7.x

; Drupal project.

projects[drupal][type] = core  
projects[drupal][version] = 7.x  
projects[drupal][download][type] = git  
projects[drupal][download][branch] = 7.x  

; Modules

projects[composer] = 1.x-dev  
projects[] = composer_autoload  
projects[] = guzzle
```

Comment: How/why did you come to the conclusion that composer_autoload is needed?

Comment: Anyways, this doesn't seem to work for me. It downloads them all and you can install them, but if you go to /admin/help/guzzle which does a test Guzzle call, it says "Class not found"

Comment: Specifically, it puts all 3 in sites/all/modules like "composer" is a regular module, and doesn't actually run any of the Composer magic.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Composer Manager](https://www.drupal.org/project/composer_manager) which would allow you to install PHP libraries managed via Composer and their dependencies on a per-project basis.

So (as per module's [README.md](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/composer_manager/tree/README.md?h=7.x-2.x)):

> If a module contains a `composer.json` file, running `composer
>   install` in its root directory will download all requirements and
>   dependencies to `vendor/` directories with their own autoloaders.

The Guzzle challenge is explained in [README.md](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/composer_manager/tree/README.md?h=7.x-2.x):

> To highlight the challenges, let's say `module_a` requires
>   `"guzzle/http": "3.7.*"` and `module_b` requires `"guzzle/service":
>   ">=3.7.0"`. At the time of this post, running `composer install` in
>   each module's directory will result in version 3.7.4 of `guzzle/http`
>   being installed in `module_a`'s `vendor/` directory and version 3.8.1
>   of `guzzle/service` being installed in `module_b`'s `vendor/`
>   directory.
>
> Because `guzzle/service` depends on `guzzle/http`, you now have
>   duplicate installs of `guzzle/http`. Furthermore, each installation
>   uses different versions of the `guzzle/http` component (3.7.4 for
>   `module_a` and 3.8.1 for `module_b`). If `module_a`'s autoloader is
>   registered first then you have a situation where version 3.8.1 of
>   `\Guzzle\Service\Client` extends version 3.7.4 of
>   `\Guzzle\Http\Client`.

So by using the Composer Manager's Solution, it finds all `composer.json` files in each enabled module's root directory and gracefully merge them into a consolidated `composer.json` file (which prevents code duplication and version mismatches).

> For the use case above, Composer will resolve both `guzzle/http` and
>   `guzzle/service` to version 3.7.4 which is a more consistent, reliable
>   environment.

---

So to answer the question: yes, you can include that in a Drupal installation in `sites/all/vendor`, e.g.

- `sites/all/vendor/composer`
- `sites/all/vendor/guzzlehttp`